# Perl regular expression to replace exact number within CDATA string

Tags: regex, perl, cdata

I have a Perl script that needs to be able to replace values contained within CDATA tags in XML.  I have the following issue:

```
my $str = "<![CDATA[Replace 00 and 00 but don't replace 1001100.]]>";
my $source = "00";
my $target = "989898";

$str =~ s/(<!\[(?i)CDATA(?-i)\[.*)$source(.*\].*)/$1$target$2/g;
```

The output that I am looking for is:

```
<![CDATA[Replace 989898 and 989898 but don't replace 1001100.]]>
```

What I am getting is:

```
<![CDATA[Replace 00 and 00 but do not replace 10011989898.]]>
```

I would also need to be able to replace `$source` if `$str` were to equal the following:

```
$str = "<![CDATA[HEREISSOMETEXT00]]>";
```

Desired output would be:

```
<![CDATA[HEREISSOMETEXT989898]]>
```

I would also need to make some changes to paths as follows:

```
my $str = "<![CDATA[/this/is/my/CHANGE_ME/path]]>";
my $source = "CHANGE_ME";
my $target = "NEW_ME";
```

Desired output would be:

```
<![CDATA[/this/is/my/NEW_ME/path]]>
```

But also need the following functionality:

```
my $str = "<![CDATA[/this/is/my/DONOTCHANGE_ME/path]]>";
my $source = "CHANGE_ME";
my $target = "NEW_ME";
```

Desired output:

```
<![CDATA[/this/is/my/DONOTCHANGE_ME/path]]>
```

Basically, I need exact matches within substrings and I cannot use any of the Perl libraries that are not delivered with Perl "out of the box."

I also had written this much simpler regex:

```
$str =~ s/$source/$target/g if $_ =~ m/<!\[CDATA/i;
```

This works great whenever I need to just replace a string like `"ABC"` or even `"AB0"` but this wreaks havoc if I need to change `"00"` to `"10"` since it replaces both `"00"` to `"10"` (desired) and `"1000"` to `"1100"` (not desired).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks...

Comment: This is why we have XML parsers.

Comment: Agreed... but cannot use.

Comment: I should also add that even if I could parse this XML with any XML module, the same work needs to be done on a string... so same issues whether XML or a Flat File without CDATA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only replace whole words, use the word boundaries `\b`:

```
s/\b00\b/10/;
```

Or, if you want to replace only when no digits precede or follow the string, use look-around assertions:

```
s/ (?<![0-9]) 00 (?![0-9]) /10/x;
```

Comment: That did it... I used the following: if ($s_param =~ /\D/)
  {
    $_ =~ s/\b$s_param\b/$t_param/g if $_ =~ m/<!\[CDATA/i;
  }
  else
  {
    $_ =~ s/(?<![0-9])$s_param(?![0-9])/$t_param/g if $_ =~ m/<!\[CDATA/i;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries:

```
my $source = qr"\b00\b";
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Answer (score 0):

The following gets me exactly what I need:

```
if ($s_param =~ /\D/)
#I'm a word
{
  $_ =~ s/\b$s_param\b/$t_param/g if $_ =~ m/<!\[CDATA/i;
}
else
#I'm a number
{
  $_ =~ s/(?<![0-9])$s_param(?![0-9])/$t_param/g if $_ =~ m/<!\[CDATA/i;
}
```